# Unable to merge data using set() in firestore, instead data is being overwritten

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to append the UserId document in the Friends collection as they accept new friend requests but the `uid` field in the document gets overwritten by the most recently accepted friend request.
I am getting this error inspite of using `merge: true`
What I expect to happen :

```js
Friends (collection)
    userId (document) 
        uid: randomValue, 
        uid: randomValue,
        .
        .and so on
```

What is actually happening :

Initially accepted friend request
[image]

After accepting friend request from another user
[image]

My code:

```js
const uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
  function onAcceptRequest() {
    firestore()
      .collection('Friends')
      .doc(`${uid}`)
      .set(
        {
          uid: senderId,
        },
        {merge: true},
      )
      .then(() => {
        firestore()
          .collection('Friends')
          .doc(`${senderId}`)
          .set(
            {
              uid: uid,
            },
            {merge: true},
          )
          .then(console.log('Befriended'))
          .then(() => deleteRequest())
          .catch(err => console.log('senders err', err));
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('currentUsers err', err));
  }
```

If there is any other method to pull off the same thing then please suggest.
Thank you.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you expect the final result to be here.  From my perspective, the code is doing exactly what it was written to do.  Did you intend something different?  If so, what exactly?  Note that a document cannot have two fields with the same name.  Each field name must be unique.

Comment: I am trying store a list of friends for specific userId(document) inside the friends collection. 
And update that list if the user accepts friend requests

Comment: I would want to store the list of friends as their uid's

Comment: You could add each new UID into a list type field in the document instead of overwriting the same uid string field each time.

Comment: I am extremely new at this, so can you please give an example how to do that?
Please.